# Creating new dataframe based on dividing rows from another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
            A B C D E
Date  
1999-01-01  1 2 3 4 5
1999-01-02  1 2 3 4 5 
1999-01-03  1 2 3 4 5 
1999-01-04  1 2 3 4 5
1999-01-05  1 2 3 4 5
```

I'm trying to divide certain rows by one and other, according to their dates, with the output as a new dataframe

What I have tried is this:

```
a = "1999-01-01"
b = "1999-01-03"
c = "1999-01-05"

Obs_1 = df.loc[b] / df.loc[a] - 1
Obs_2 = df.loc[c] / df.loc[b] - 1

df_1 = pd.concat([Obs_1, Obs_2], axis = 1)
df_1
```

However, it's just giving me NaN throughout ie:

```
            A    B   C   D   E   A    B   C   D   E
Date  
1999-01-01  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 
1999-01-03  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 
1999-01-05  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

I'm a bit confused as to why it's returning three rows when there are only two things in the concat()...likely related, I also don't understand why it's returning NaN rather than the result of b/a and c/b.

As a side-bar question, when I just examine Obs_1 it returns

```
             A    B   C   D   E
Date  
1999-01-01  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 
1999-01-03  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

rather than the expected result of a series with b / a

Please could someone steer me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Comment: whats your intended output? your code works fine for me - as in returns a new dataframe with `0's` as the values in two columns.

Comment: I’m shooting for df_1where the columns are as the initial df and the rows are Obs_1, Obs_2. Although I’m agnostic about how exactly it looks provided that the division is occurring. But I can see from the (above) output of Obs_1 that it isn’t dividing the way I’m expecting

Comment: Also...is there a way of ensuring Obs_1 is returned as a series? I don’t understand why it’s being returned as a Dataframe. Thanks